# problem with my API in Jenkins: Invalid password/token for user:

Tags: api, docker, jenkins, flask, basic-authentication

When i try to connect to my Api with basic authentification on my Jenkinsfile after successfully running my container: (toto is the username/python is the password)

**curl -u toto:python -X GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/pozos/api/v1.0/get_student_ages**

i received this error in my console Output on my Jenkins server:

**Error 401 Invalid password/token for user: toto
HTTP ERROR 401
Problem accessing /pozos/api/v1.0/get_student_ages. Reason:
    Invalid password/token for user: toto**

Jenkins successfully builds my dockerfile and runs my container on the port 8080,i don't understand why it doesn't work...everything works normally when i don't use Jenkins,

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the password will not work. You will need to create an API Token for the user. And then use that token as the password in the call.

So your call will be changed to

```
curl -u toto:<token> -X GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/pozos/api/v1.0/get_student_ages
```

Here is the link on how to generate and use the token

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

> The API token is available in your personal configuration page. Click your name on the top right corner on every page, then click
>   "Configure" to see your API token. (The URL $root/me/configure is a
>   good shortcut.) You can also change your API token from here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but it does not work...i think it's possible to use the password or the token as you said,the problem is elsewhere